# How to access variables in blocks in Fuel CMS?

Tags: php, fuelcms

I have been using **Fuel CMS** to develop a website, and I was thinking of using *blocks* to make my pages dynamic using CMS, but I can't access any passed variables inside block.

#### FUEL CMS Page

```
{fuel_block(array(
        'view' => 'nt_project_card',
        'vars' => array(
            'project_title' => 'Test Project',
            'project_desc' => 'Some details about project',
            'project_link' => 'projects/project1'
        )))}
```

#### FUEL CMS Block

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{fuel_var('img')}" alt="Project Image">
<div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{fuel_var('project_title', 'Title')}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{fuel_var('project_desc')}</p>
    <a href="{site_url(fuel_var('project_link'))}" class="btn btn-link">Read More...</a>
</div>
```

Where am I going wrong? I have seen documentation (which is already very vague) and questions on forum but they didn't help either. I can only see my default value along with the rendered block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I don't need to use any function I can just go with the usual `$variable` to use the passed variables in blocks.

Answer (score 0):

can use

```
<?php echo $this->fuel->blocks->render('block_name'); ?>
```

same as application\views_blocks files